# Is it a bad idea using a single sequence generator in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, sequence-sql

This is a generic question about PostgreSQL `sequence` **performance**, for if they could be a **bottleneck** in high-write-concurrency databases, when choosing use one instead of one per table.

I outlined *performance* and *bottleneck* because I am perfectly aware that PostgreSQL sequences are safe, as explained elsewhere and in
[PostgreSQL: Is using SELECT nextval generator thread safe, in harsh multiuser environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215151/postgresql-is-using-select-nextval-generator-thread-safe-in-harsh-multiuser-en). Also, I don't mind the holes the sequence may generate.

I have a number of tables (< 60), each one with its own surrogate primary key `id`, declared as

```sql
id int generated by default as identity
```

Most of the tables holding public entities are detailed by a subset of shared generic tables. For example, tables as `product`, `category`, `post` or `user` are detailed by table `text`, that holds all the varchars of a public object for the different languages on the application.

As the `id` columns of all those public entities may have the same value, I have to use the pair

```sql
object_id    int not null,
object_type  tobject not null,
```

to uniquely refer `text` to the public entities it details.

It is clear than having `id` columns with unique values, coming from a single sequence, would allow me to remove the `object_type` columns from all of the shared tables and the SQL code of the application. It would also simplify (ad hopefully accelerate) indexing on shared tables.

As I am planning to increase the number of shared tables, my question is how the sequence generators perform on high-write concurrency. Will a single sequence generator be a bottleneck when many concurrent `insert into` try to issue a `nextval`? Would it be better to stay with one per table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not commenting in your design, a single sequence will be no problem.

Sequences are optimized for concurrency, and if `nextval` actually threatens to be a bottleneck, you can change the sequence to use `CACHE n` for `n > 1`. Then every call to the sequence actually gets the next `n` values, which are cached by the database session.

Make sure to use `bigint`, not `integer` as the data type, so that you cannot run out of sequence values.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. Yes bigint will be necessary. A bad idea shared facts tables?

Comment: You cannot have foreign keys any more that guarantee that you don't end up with orphaned entries. But perhaps that is worth it.

Comment: ah ok, that's "discounted" :-)